# Would it be safe, effective and still flexible to use RAII approach in C++ with WinAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi

A lot of WinAPI objects, such as handles, events or sockets, are resources. I found it safe and efficient to wrap them in RAII classes.

Are there any pitfalls in doing that? Is it common practice or, instead, a bright, misleading idea? Or, maybe, there are already libraries for that? (Although I couldn't find anything worthy.)

Mostly, I'm interested in wrappers for 'small' objects like files, sockets, events and threads, that are not related to GUI or COM. Libraries like MFC or ATL may do such job but don't seem to be lightweight and no-overhead what I'm asking about.

Comment: You couldn't find *any* library that wraps the Windows API?! For real? What about MFC, WTL, ATL?

Comment: A main pitfall is that the Windows API is very *weakly typed* (even with `STRICT` defined). For example, which function you should use to destroy an `HDC` depends on how that `HDC` was acquired. So you may have to use more than one wrapper for each Windows API handle type. There are also numerous other pitfalls, and what to consider a pitfall is very subjective. Voting to close as too broad / subjective.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm aware of MFC and ATL but these libraries are certainly not what I'm looking for. I don't need neither UI components nor something that is intended to simplify work with COM. Question is about much simpler things.

Comment: `GetClipboardData()` for example returns a `HANDLE` you **must** not free, and other places where you may think you need to keep a `HANDLE` around you should actually free it, because e.g. it will be duplicated somewhere anyway. But generally, I do like encapsulating them. I use `unique_handle`s, `pipe`s which have two `unique_handle`s, a `scoped_clipboard`, RAII wrappers for `CreateJobObjectA()` to terminate child processes etc.

Comment: @melak47 that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I honestly tried to reformulate this question somehow  but finally couldn't came up with something better...